# CASE expression in insert with ContentProvider

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I visited [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com) and made some tests.

I wanted to get a SQL statement that would let me insert a row, and have a field (below is called *active*) whose value depends on the table being empty or not.

I used the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE kids (
        identifier    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
        name          VARCHAR, 
        surname       VARCHAR, 
        active        INTEGER);


INSERT INTO 
    kids
VALUES 
    (1, "name1", "surname1", CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM kids) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END);  

INSERT INTO 
    kids
VALUES 
    (2, "name2", "surname2", CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM kids) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END);
```

And I get the following result when performing a `SELECT * FROM kids`:

```
+---+-------+----------+---+
| 1 | name1 | surname1 | 1 |
+---+-------+----------+---+
| 2 | name2 | surname2 | 0 |
+---+-------+----------+---+
```

This is perfect. The thing is, how do I perform this *insert* in `Android` using `SQLite` and `ContentProviders`?. Both *insert* (on `ContentProviders` and `SQLite` instance take a `ContentValues` as a parameter, and I can't add a subquery there, it would be literally read and written.

Is it even possible to achieve this ? If you can think of any other approach, it is also welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: `SQLiteDatabase#execSQL`?

Comment: @pskink You just made me look like an idiot. Well done. Feel free to post an answer, if no one posts a better one I will accept yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of achieving your requirement would be to check the value of underlying field before insertion and then insert the entire data along with computed value in active field

Answer (score 0):

`ContentValues` ensures that it contents are never interpreted as SQL, so this is not possible.

Unless you actually need to provide data to other apps, do not use content providers. (And if you need to give data to other apps, it would be a bad idea to allow them to execute arbitrary SQL.)

Comment: I use `ContentProviders` because I can easily manage screen refreshes when data is changed. Is there a better way to achieve this ?

Comment: Could you give more details on this ?